# Select MongoDB database in Python2 by variable value

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, nosql

I wanna select MongoDB db with Python2. If I use this code I haven't any kind of problem:

```
db = client.nameofdb
```

If I create a var called DBNAME, which value is "nameofdb", like this

```
DBNAME = nameofdb

db = client.DBNAME
```

I have some problem with my MongoDB because I can't access into nameofdb database: Mongo create for me another db called DBNAME. I just want to use some kind of "constant" name in my project. How can I do for?

Comment: `db = client[DBNAME]`? Works for me in python.

Comment: Yeah it work for me too! Thanks Neil!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try accessing it as a dictionary: `db = client[DBNAME]`

Comment: I'm new and I can't Up your answer (I have only 6 reputation), but I've solve my problems because of you. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @SalvoBertoncini You can mark it as the right answer. The green mark.

Comment: Done! Thanks a lot!